# Commenting in CSS (//) equals "none"?

Tags: themes, css, code

I am beginner in site development and made all changes in my main theme. Now I want to transfer it all into child theme and faced this question. Are examples below equal?

```
.entry-header-wrapper {

  //margin-bottom: 40px;

}

.entry-header-wrapper {

  margin-bottom: none;

}
```

Comment: `//` is not a valid way to comment in CSS, that will be a CSS 'error'. If you are asking how to override that element's `margin-bottom` in your child theme, then the stuff in your child theme's stylesheet will override the parent theme's, as long as the stylesheet is included after the parent's one. `margin-bottom` should be `0`, not `none`, if you want there to be `0` margin.

Comment: The default (initial) value for `margin-bottom` is `0` [see](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin-left)

Answer (score 1):

No. The first example is invalid CSS, the second one valid. In CSS, [you can only comment with `/*` and `*/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments). If you are unsure, there are tools such as [CSSLint](http://csslint.net) or the [W3C's CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check your code.

Also setting a value to `none` or not setting the value at all is something different as well.

Comment: Thank you! One more question:
.entry-footer {
  padding: 0 80px;
}
This was the first version. I changed it like that in parent theme:
.entry-footer {
  
}

But how do I show this change in child theme, is it like this?
.entry-footer {
  padding: none
}

Comment: @VladislavMakeev This is too much to explain here (also I voted to close your question, as it is off topic for this site, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - yours is a general CSS question). Short answer: `.entry-footer {padding: 0;}`. Long answer: Please properly learn CSS